# Are UUID's in Android specific to application within the device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid

looking in the the web for answers, I am sort of confused id  UUID's are unique to a service within the device. I want to know if an application on a particular device can generate a UUID during installation which will be same in all the other devices where the app is installed?

so that a search can be performed using UUID to find how many devices  are using this particular application using bluetooth. or is there any other way to do that using UUID.( like 
fetchUuidsWithSdp ())

I am new to Android programming. so be kind if I am being Naive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUIDs are generated as random numbers or other algorithm intended to guarantee that no UUID is ever generated twice.

If you want multiple instances of an application to use the same UUID, you'll have to generate it in advance and include it in your application.

There's no reason why you can't do this, and a web search for "UUID generator" will turn up several sites that will provide you with one.

Comment: @Edwards Thanks.. which means that I need to generate the UUID(via a generator ) in advance and then hardcode that in the installation file, so that it remains the same in multiple instances of the app when the app is installed on different devices